# How to time something in Go, which takes less than a nanosecond?

Tags: go, benchmarking, duration

How would I proceed if I want to compare the time of two functions, but the functions take less than a nanosecond?

```golang
t := time.Now()
_ = fmt.Sprint("Hello, World!")
d := time.Since(t)
d.Round(0)
fmt.Println(d.Nanoseconds()) // Prints 0
```

I could run the function a couple of times and divide the time by the number of executions, but I would rather like a way to time a single execution. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Benchmarking a single execution won't give you useful results, ever. Thats why benchmarking libraries call your function thousands, sometimes millions of times.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that :) This is more or less out of curiosity :) The default benchmarking features of go are solid for me! But I still would like to know if I can measure times under a nanosecond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If timing a function is generating a time less than a nanosecond, it usually means that the code was optimized out.

Compilers can detect that some code has no side effects, and decide "why would I do that".

1/(1 ns) is 1 Ghz.  Modern desktop computers cap out at about 5 Ghz, give or take.  So for it to be less than 1 ns, the operation plus the overhead of getting the time has to take fewer than 5 CPU cycles.  At that level of resolution, the CPU isn't doing one thing at a time.  The start of an instruction and the end can be multiple cycles apart, with the operation being pipelined.

So you have to look at the machine code and understand the architecture to determine what the real cost is, including what parts of the CPU's resources are used, and how it would conflict with other operations you might want to do nearby.

So even "before" and "after" stop having reasonable meaning at sub-1-ns time resolutions on most CPUs fast enough to run above 1 Ghz.

Answer (score 2):

Something you could do, is answer the question "how many runs before this thing
takes at least one nanosecond":

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   d := 1
   for {
      t := time.Now()
      for e := d; e > 0; e-- {
         fmt.Sprint("Hello, World!")
      }
      if time.Since(t) > 0 { break }
      d *= 2
   }
   println(d)
}
```